# Fade the body in javascript

Tags: javascript, background, document, opacity

I am using an 'onclick' to view a picture and text. I now want to fade the background.

> document.body.style.opacity = 0.1;

The page isn't fading or changing. So what am I doing wrong?

The full JS file is:

```
function changeImage()
```

thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/ru3pdqc7/

Comment: You need to provide us some more information about your sourcecode

Comment: what type of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opacity` on *body* tag will change whole page style.

You probably want to change only `background image` or `color`.

*1. color*

You need `rgb` format for color `0,0,0`, and just add `alpha` to make it `rgba`.

`document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.1);"`

*2. image*

You need `pseudo element` to change *opacity* without affecting *body* tag.

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

body:after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Here is *[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7utL5anr/)*

**UPDATE**

If you just need an **overlay** when your image is enlarged, 
than you should use overlay element, like every lightbox plugin.

Style overlay

CSS

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7); //choose opacity
    z-index: -1; // set z-index smaller than image and text
}
```

JS

```
if () {
    //Create element and append it to body.

    var page = document.body;
    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.id = "overlay";
    page.appendChild(overlay);

} else {
    //Remove element

    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    overlay.parentNode.removeChild(overlay);
}
```

Comment: no because when i click a picture, the picture is enlarged and text is shown to tell about the picture. when it happens i want the background to fade or grey out.

Comment: I updated the answer to include better approach. Seems that you need some overlay behind image, like almost any lightbox, modal, popup plugins have.

Comment: in the else bit when i click i want the opacity to go back to how it was. how do i do that?

Comment: This method add and remove element, without changing any of styles.    If you want to change opacity, change `alpha` value of `background-color` ***rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)***. Value can be from 0 up to 1. You can use `overlay.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1);"`

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that what you really want is for the whole background to darken, you can do this by just adding a few simple lines to your css:

```
html {
    background-color: black;
}
body {
    background-color: white; /*<< or whatever it was previously,
                               but it has to have a color*/
}
```

And now it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/ru3pdqc7/1/

You may wish to add `margin: 0;` to your body, to prevent the black sides of the html from being shown, as [demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/ru3pdqc7/4/).

Or, instead of css, 100% js:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.body.style.margin = 0;
```

[in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru3pdqc7/8/)

Animations are added within fiddle, just to show you how you can fade it in and out. Really, it's all based on that simple idea.

NOTE: to avoid having your pop-out fade as well, you need to set its opacity to 1 at every stage of your animation.

Comment: does this fade it out?